# Multiple main C++ files in a single project in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I do not regularly write code. There are times I write code daily for 6 months, and then do not code for up to 2 years. This approach has forced me to keep a bunch or reference code that I (and other much, much better programmers) have written. I refer to this "library" when writing code after a long period; I read it, I execute it, and that is a massive help in refreshing myself. This system has served me very well with Eclipse & Java over the past 5 years.

I am now learning C++ and am using Code::Blocks. I would like to somehow stuff a bunch of C++ files that have main methods into a single Code::Blocks project. I am willing to rewrite the code to achieve this task (if it's reasonable...)

I am not the first to look for a meaningful answer for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917504/how-can-i-make-multiple-programs-in-a-single-project-in-codeblocks and https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/3opp5r/how_to_run_multiple_cpp_files_separately_in_same/

I do not want to change the IDE or compare it to other IDEs. What I am looking for, is the ability to execute one of hundreds of tiny programs that are in a well organized in an expandable file tree in C::B quickly and easily. If I put each C++ file with a main in it's own project I will have so many C::B projects that it will be unreasonable.

I do understand that C::B is not Eclipse and C++ is not Java, and that C::B is intended to have a single c++ file with a main function per project.

Any answers, and even very creative answers would be very appreciated! Scripts, settings, how to rewrite my code, whatever - if you have a suggestion I would love to hear it so I may consider it.

In the interest of full disclosure, currently I am keeping all my tiny programs in directories and use the O/S to drill through the directories and simply double click on the .cpp file which C::B opens. I am willing to dramatically modify my code to be able to achieve the objective.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: did you got a better answer? I also have the same issue.

Comment: @pio I ended up sorting all my code in directories - each directory holds related source files. When I want to run specific .cpp and .h files I remove all the current files from the workspace, and put the files I want to work with. This system provides organization I want, permits coding via CodeBlocks, and overcomes the limitation of having only 1 main method between all the source files.

Comment: thx.
But It's still an headache to remove the files every time you want to run. It sounds to me like there should be a way just to run specific main via the code blocksmanager?

Answer (score 7):

To compile and run a single `main()` file in a Code::Blocks **project** with multiple `main()` files:

1. In the "Projects" tab on the left, right-click on a file that you do **not** want to compile.
2. In the menu that appears, point to `Options`, and uncheck **both** `Compile file` and `Link file`.
3. This has to be done for **all** the files that you do not want to compile.
4. Now, when the project is built and run with `F9`, only the desired file will be compiled; the others will be ignored.

**Note:** It is not necessary to create a project in Code::Blocks to compile and run single file. To compile and run single files (without creating projects)

1. Just click on `File` -> `Empty` -> `New file`.
2. Save the file with `.cpp` extension anywhere (not in a project).
3. To compile and run the file, just press `F9` or `Build` -> `Build and run`
4. However, such files (without projects) cannot be debugged. The most appropriate thing would be to just have a project with multiple `main()` files, as explained in the early part of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've learned Java before, and am starting to learn C++ now.

When using Code::Blocks as my primary C++ IDE, I met the same problem as you. Although I found nothing useful on the Internet, I managed to figure it out on my own. Here is my solution.

1. In your `Management` panel, find your current project and right click, choose `Close Project`. (We won't use project to manage our code for this purpose.)
2. Still in the `Management` panel, find the `Files` tab, navigate to your working directory, right click on it and choose `Make Root`.

And we are done!

When you want to add a new code file, right click on your folder and choose `New file...`, enter your file name with the extension of `.cpp`. Then you can just use your C::B as before. Without the limit of project, C::B will just compile your current C++ file and run it on its own. Keyboard shortcuts `F9` and the `Run and Build` button still works.

The only disadvantage is that you can see `.exe` and `.o` files in your file list, which is a little untidy. I'm still trying to find how to hide them in the list.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your kind advice. In fact, I've already used Python for my data analysis courses and currently planning to take Go as my next learning goal. The reason why I'm learning C++ is just pure curiosity.

Comment: JerryLu @RannLifshitz I don't see Files tab in Management window. Any chance it has been removed in SDK version 2.6.0? –

Answer (score 2):

How about using the precompiler? You can surround each `main` with:

```
#ifdef EXECUTE_EXAMPLE_1
int main() { return 0; } // example of one of the "mains" in one cpp
#endif

#ifdef EXECUTE_EXAMPLE_2
int main() { return 0; } // another "main" in an other cpp
#endif

#ifdef EXECUTE_EXAMPLE_3
int main() { return 0; } // yet another "main" somewhere else
#endif
```

And creating a header, included by all "mains" where you can define one to run:

```
#ifndef _EXECUTION_HEADER_H_
#define _EXECUTION_HEADER_H_

// Uncomment one and only one
#define EXECUTE_EXAMPLE_1
//#define EXECUTE_EXAMPLE_2
//#define EXECUTE_EXAMPLE_3

#endif // _EXECUTION_HEADER_H_
```

This could be a quick and dirty "build system" for your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what they were trying to accomplish. 
No, you can't have two main files in the same Project, but you can have a lot of smaller project programs saved to a workspace which allows you to run and test them each individually.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHGIIp3rGO8

Comment: Although a youtube video may be helpful, it isn't a replacement for a complete answer. If you look at the other answers, you'll see what an expected answer looks like. The youtube video is an optional addition