# Creating multiple files in code::blocks in C++ under 1 project

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I intend to create lots of small programs each with a main() function and run them separately under 1 project, in code::blocks in C++.
But code::blocks creates the first file "main.cpp" which contains the main() function.
Then, when I create another file with main() function, in the same project, it shows multiple definition of "main" error.
Unlike in BlueJ, where I used Java, I was able to create multiple files, each with a main() function, in the same project.
I searched a lot, but couldn't find relevant answers.
This is the link to a similar question asked.
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455052/multiple-main-c-files-in-a-single-project-in-codeblocks)
I followed the most appropriate answer to that question, but that couldn't solve my purpose.
Please help.

Comment: One single *workspace*, multiple *projects*.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude. I have found a way to fulfill my purpose, by commenting all files except the one, which needs to be compiled. This can be done in 1 project.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new project each time, just create a new file with a new function like the hello function.
Here is screenshot https://prnt.sc/avPJAeZNHoLK , then put the same function in the body of the main file like this https://prnt.sc/d93F8Unk56s6.
main() will run along with new function. output will like this https://prnt.sc/QIIrcRBudRH1
You can also comment out main file code.
Happy coding :)

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow! Usually, sharing the code is better than images. Please [edit] your answer to include the necessary code parts.